# How can I see data usage by file type?

Tags: php

Is there a PHP script or a way to calculate the file space usage of each file type? I am trying to create an overview of each filetype, which includes total file size and number of files for each extension (.mp3, .mp4, etc) for a specific directory (and all of it's subdirectories) on a server.

How can I do this?

Comment: There is a function with which you can figure out the size of a file, and there are functions for getting file names and directory contents. Put them together with a little loop and some simple arithmetic and you're set.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll create an associative array in which your keys will be your files' extensions.

Second of all, you'll iterate through your folder(treat all files) and do something like:

```
$extensions_array[pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)] += filesize($filename);
```

Then you should have an associative array containing the filesize for each extension.